# On add element in queue call a listener to notify queue element is variable

Tags: java, queue

I want when ever we add element in queue , I should call a method to fetch as soon as element added in queue.

```
package com.java.listner;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class QueueListner {



public static Queue<String> queue=new LinkedList<String>();

    public boolean add(String e) {
        itemAvailableInqueue();
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        queue.add("record1");
        System.out.println(queue.poll());
    }

    public void itemAvailableInqueue() {
        int size = queue.size();
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println(queue.poll());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In simple, I want a listner for queue operation.

Comment: Write a decorator

Comment: do you hava any example . how to write decorator for queue as listener class

Comment: You can also look at [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: You can try an `Observer pattern`

Comment: Once queue is added element, i want to pull. But i don't know when element will add. Whenever it will add i have to call my method to pull it. Any one know, i need some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a listener to a queue, you need to make it "listenable", the simplest way to do this is [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). This pattern targets adding features in a class while keeping its base functionality.

In case of `Queue`, you just extend a [`AbstractQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html) class, overriding its `offer` method. Other methods just delegate to a backing queue, since they don't need to notify listeners.

```
public class ListenableQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E> {

    interface Listener<E> {
        void onElementAdded(E element);
    }

    private final Queue<E> delegate;  // backing queue
    private final List<Listener<E>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListenableQueue(Queue<E> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public ListenableQueue<E> registerListener(Listener<E> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e) {
        // here, we put an element in the backing queue, 
        // then notify listeners
        if (delegate.offer(e)) {
            listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.onElementAdded(e));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // following methods just delegate to backing instance
    @Override public E poll() { return delegate.poll(); }
    @Override public E peek() { return delegate.peek(); }
    @Override public int size() { return delegate.size(); }
    @Override public Iterator<E> iterator() { return delegate.iterator(); }

}
```

This `ListenableQueue` implements `Queue` interface thus has all `Queue` functionality considering properties of backing delegate queue (i.e. capacity constraints, blocking behavior, etc), so can be used like any other `Queue`.

Usage example:

```
// we create new `LinkedList` as a backing queue and decorate it
ListenableQueue<String> q = new ListenableQueue<>(new LinkedList<>());

// register a listener which polls a queue and prints an element 
q.registerListener(e -> System.out.println(q.poll()));

// voila!
q.add("record1");
```

Comment: Thanks , it's working fine.  But i have doubt after executing and debugging properly. on ListenableQueue class,   delegate.offer(e) adding new element in    Queue<E> delegate but how listeners updates with same record . and sending in q.registerListener(e -> System.out.println(q.poll())); method.        ListenableQueue class have memory instance for delegate queue and listeners .  I am confusing that is listners have instance of queue in stack.   In debugging showing listeners has arraylist of same class object and this object has arraylist of records what i added.

Comment: Here, listener instance is created using lambda expression `e -> System.out.println(q.poll())`. You can create in more "classical" manner using abstract class or a class implementing `ListenableQueue.Listener<String>` interface.

Comment: listener would have original queue "in stack" simply because it operates that queue which holds that original queue, thus holding a references to those objects. You may create a listener just operating element: `e -> System.out.println(e)`

Comment: Thanks and i got it.